# if else condition inside of forfiles loop

Tags: batch-file

I've inherited a batch file, and in it, I've got the following command -

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c IF @ISDIR==TRUE rmdir @FILE /q" >> C:\Apps\%dt%\%dt%.log  2>&1
```

In the log, I get the following error:

> ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I put an else condition so that it outputs the name of the file not found, instead the Error Message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ther error comes from `forfiles` when it is executed in a directory with no content (no files and no directories). Remember that `forfiles` searches the current working directory if no path is specified explicitly by the `/P` switch, and the search mask defaults to `*` if switch `/M` is not given, hence matching all items. So the error you encounter can only occur with an empty working directory.
The error has got nothing to do with the `if @isdir==TRUE` query.

If you want a specific message to appear in your log, you could check the `ErrorLevel` state after `forfiles` has been executed, which is `1` in case no items match the search criteria, and `0` if at least one item matches:

```
forfiles /S /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE rmdir @file" || echo "%CD%" is empty. >> "C:\Apps\%dt%\%dt%.log" 2> nul
```

This writes the message `"%CD%" is empty` into the log with `%CD%` replaced by the current directory.
The `2> nul` suppresses the error message `ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.`.
The `||` operator is conditionally concatenates commands and lets the right one execute only if the left one has been completed successfully, meaning that `ErrorLevel` is `0`.